# Multiple swagger JSON file generation for different API groups

Tags: swagger, swashbuckle

I have swagger configured in my solution and it is showing up the API documentation properly. Now recently I have developed some new APIs in the same solution and these are also showing up in API documentation and these projects also follow the same naming conventions.
Now my requirement is I want to segregate the new API documentation from the older ones so basically I want two JSON files generated one foe each, old API, AND new API.

My Swagger configuration looks like the following.

```
  Config.EnableSwagger(@"api-docs/{apiVersion}",
            c =>
            {
                c.SingleApiVersion("v1", "SAMPLE API");
                c.UseFullTypeNameInSchemaIds();
                c.ResolveConflictingActions(apiDescriptions => apiDescriptions.First());
                foreach (String x in Directory.GetFiles(Path.GetDirectoryName(Uri.UnescapeDataString(new UriBuilder(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().CodeBase).Path)), "*.dll")
                    .Where(f => Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(f).ToLower().Contains("sample") ****&& !Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(f).ToLower().Contains("sample.api"))****
                     
                    .Select(f => String.Format(@"{0}\{1}.xml", Path.GetDirectoryName(f), Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(f)))
                    .Where(File.Exists))
                {
                    c.IncludeXmlComments(x);
                }
                c.OperationFilter<AddRequiredHeaderParameter>();
            });
```

My New API projects are named sample.api.test and old API projects are named sample.web.test.
I added the && part in the where clause to ignore picking my new files in the first JSON doc generation but of no luck. I am new to this and really don't know if it is possible to have two JSON depending on project names. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you looks into `MultipleApiVersions`? I think that is what you should use instead of SingleApiVersion, here is an example: https://github.com/heldersepu/Swagger-Net-Test/blob/MultiApiVersions/Swagger_Test/App_Start/SwaggerConfig.cs#L64

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this using IDocumentFilter as follows.

```
internal class SwaggerFilterOutControllers : IDocumentFilter
    {
        void IDocumentFilter.Apply(SwaggerDocument swaggerDoc, SchemaRegistry schemaRegistry, IApiExplorer apiExplorer)
        {
            
            var apiKeys = swaggerDoc.paths.Select(s => s.Key).ToList();
            foreach (var apiKey in apiKeys)
            {
                if (swaggerDoc.info.title == "old API" && apiKey.StartsWith("/latapi"))
                    swaggerDoc.paths.Remove(apiKey);
                else if (swaggerDoc.info.title == "New Public API" && !apiKey.StartsWith("/latapi"))
                    swaggerDoc.paths.Remove(apiKey);
            }
}
}
```

and then in the enableswagger() method i called this filter as

```
c.DocumentFilter<SwaggerFilterOutControllers>();
```